# javax.naming.CommunicationException on executing the client

Tags: jms, jboss7.x

I have synchronized my session baeans with the jboss server. But on running the client,
i am getting the following exception. pls tell me the solution if anyone knows!!

javax.naming.Communication Exception: Could not obtain connection to any of these urls: localhost:8080 and discovery failed with error: javax.naming.CommunicationException: Receive timed out [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: Receive timed out] [Root exception is javax.naming.Communication Exception: Failed to retrieve stub from server localhost:8080 [Root exception is java.io.EOFException]]

Comment: public class BeanClient {
public static void main(String [] args ) {
Hashtable env = new Hashtable();
env.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "org.jnp.interfaces.NamingContextFactory");
env.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "localhost:8080");
try {
Context ctx = new InitialContext(env);
Object obj = ctx.lookup("LocalHomeInterface");
LocalHomeInterface lhi =(LocalHomeInterface) PortableRemoteObject.narrow(obj, LocalHomeInterface.class);
LocalInterface li = lhi.create();
System.out.println(li.hello());
} catch (Exception e) {
System.err.println(e);
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Check the host and port where your jboss is running.